# Multilevel dropdown menu using Vue js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, navbar

This navbar has a 1 level dropdown menu. I want to create up to 3 levels but when adding a grandchildren condition to the children it won't work. With this setting, how would I be able to create a 3 level dropdown menu? I have been trying some code for a few days now and I can't seem to find a way to implement up to 3 levels on this menu. I have made a CodeSandbox for help. This is not the original project but it is the main Navbar component. Any suggestions on how to make a multilevel menu ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/header-issue-3-level-menu-needed-4vp1v

Comment: you should put minimum relevant code in the question ... but, have you noticed all the Vue errors at your link? videoContent not defined, Unknown element `<Banner>, <ServiceSection> <MobileFeature>` and at least 7 more ... your current code has a lot of issues, so not sure where to start with helping - not even sure which view is displaying to be honest

Comment: What was uploaded is a minimal part of the entire webpage, those are current issues on the CodeSandbox sample project created but not on the official code. I just need to implement a 3rd level menu based on the current Header.vue code displayed on the homepage of the webpage for visual reference.

Comment: "uploaded to codesandbox" is not the same as "code in the question"

Comment: It is essentially the same but in sandbox is missing all the sass files and since they are too many it won't let me upload them.